# Basic Java GUI: Drawing Multiple Shapes allowing user to pick new color for each

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, drawing

I'm currently getting into basic Java GUI programming. I'm in a class where we are cramming GUI work in over the last two weeks of the semester saying "learn this" via a project. Since GUIs are new to me, they are proving to be daunting tasks. I feel like, if you can point me in the right direction, I can resume working on this assignment by myself...I just need that little bit of information that bumps me over the "hump".

So basically, the assignment is to create a window in which a user can click somewhere within a JPanel to draw an ellipse, and repeat this process as many times as needed. In it's most basic form, I have this program running well. However, the professor wants us to add some features:

- Ten buttons a user can click to change the color of the next ellipse.
- Two text fields where the user can enter the height and width of the next ellipse they draw.
- A text field where the user can enter the desired degrees of rotation for the next ellipse drawn.

I am currently stuck on the first part, adding the ability to change color based on which button they press.

There are three classes involved: MainClient, SpriteField, and RoundSprite.

In MainClient, I have an event handler for each button....something like:

```
JButton btnRed = new JButton("Red");
btnRed.setBackground(Color.RED);
btnRed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        colorPick = "red";
    }
});
btnRed.setBounds(5, 228, 117, 29);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnRed);
```

Then, in RoundSprite, I have a method called pickColor, which sets a Color-type variable to be used when drawing an ellipse ( in DrawSprite() ):

```
public void pickColor(String colorPick)
{
    if (colorPick.equals("black"))
        mColor =  Color.BLACK;
    if (colorPick.equals("white"))
        mColor = Color.WHITE;
    if (colorPick.equals("cyan"))
        mColor = Color.CYAN;
    //etcetera....
}
```

The Color-type variable mColor is then used in a DrawSprite method, also in the RoundSprite class:

```
public void DrawSprite(Graphics2D g2)
{
    AffineTransform tOldTransform = g2.getTransform();

    g2.setColor(mColor);      
    g2.translate(mX, mY);

    g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 30, 50));

    g2.setTransform(tOldTransform);
}
```

When I run my code, however,  the color of the ellipse does not change. The ellipses I click to draw, remain black. I'm not sure where the program is "losing" the color I choose when it calls DrawSprite().

Any input/assistance/advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Create a "shape", which knows how to paint it self and what it should paint itself,,place these in a List of some kind and loop through it and paint these within your paintComponent method

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that the background(Jpanel) I am drawing on is gray. So the ellipses remaining black doesn't mean they're not being added to a list or drawn...they are. My problem is that I can't switch colors. The program is supposed to work so that I can click on a button for any one of ten colors, and then click somewhere on the JPanel to draw an ellipse of my chosen color.

Comment: Yep, wrap the painting of the shape with the color in custom class...

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap"?

Comment: Basically it describes a class which "wraps" other classes or acts as a container for.  In this, it contains the shape to be painted and the color, within a single class.  But instead of reinventing the wheel, it simply wraps the pre existing shape and color classes